# How to display QR code in JSP page?

Tags: jsp, qr-code

I am using Eclipse Mars Version with Appache Tomcat 6. I want to make QR code of input string from JSP page and display it in the next page.

I tried these steps in my JSP.`// Create Java QRCode object 
QRCode barcode = new QRCode();

// Set QRCode data text to encode
barcode.setData("Create-QR-Code-in-Java");

// Generate QRCode barcode & encode into GIF format
barcode.drawBarcode("C://barcode-qrcode.gif"); `

Comment: Please note, this question has been asked before (in a different way). Please consider the answers provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195007/what-is-the-best-java-qr-code-generator-library

Comment: Where can I get source code?

Comment: Here is one example I found http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-qr-codes-java-servlet-qr-code-java/ . Here is the Git page for QRGen that contains some information as well https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen

Comment: It contains Java servelet code and Android Code.Will It work in JSP? Can you give some JSP code or links.

Comment: where to get .jar file of https://github.com/zxing/zxing ?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried developing QR code in asp.net and is working well, I am placing the image For developing QR code

Download QRCoder.dll Online

**HTML code**
[image]

**Coading part**
[image]

Hope this will resolve your issue